# How to run .swc file in flex project?

Tags: apache-flex, swc

I have a .swc file and I learned how to add that swc file into the library. I will be happy if any one explain how to use this .swc file into my flex project and run that with an example .

Comment: An SWC is a library file and contains functions and objects to be called from your code; it's not executable on its own.  Without being more specific about which library you're using and what you want to do with it, we're unlikely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a namespace to access members of the swc.  For example, in  your mxml application tag you would have

```
... xmlns:mySwc="com.project.foo.*" ...
```

This gives the alias mySwc to the swc located in com/project/foo.  You would then access its class like

```
<mySwc:swcClass ... />
```